# C#: Best structure for storing a set of string values needed in a project?

Tags: c#, csv

I have a small csv file with a header row. I want to select a row from the file which matches a search (one row per search), then have the values of that row available to my class. I'd like to refer to the values by the column names as defined by the header in the csv.

I have already written the code for reading the csv, getting the header, executing the search, etc.

I'm looking for opinions regarding the "best" (or most aligned with CSharp best practices) manner for storing the row values so they can be referenced by column_names.

I need the values to be exposed to other classes in my project. Should I make a class with public properties set to the values? A dictionary object as a property? A DataTable? Or something else?

There are around 20 columns, so 20 string key/value pairs I want to reference by column_name.

Thanks.

Comment: A class with public properties for the columns, and then a `List<T>` of the class for the rows would be the simplest approach, IMO.

Comment: If the column names are dynamic, then maybe make a class that has a `List` of `Dictionary<string, object>` for the values and a `List<string>` for the column names (so that you know what keys to expect in each dictionary without having to check them directly).

Comment: Alternatively you could look into using `dynamic` objects instead of dictionaries - I think MVC's `ViewBag` is an example.

Comment: A `struct` may even be an option here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If columns are dynamic, then the class should look like:

```
class csvFile
{
   public List<string> ColumnHeaders { get; set; }
   public List<Dictionary<string, string>> Rows { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I apologize for not awarding you the answer earlier. I believe this is the approach I'm going to take. I like @pål-jørgen valdersnes comment as well but as you mention if the header is dynamic this works better. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

A public class with properties is a good way to go regarding best practises, this also allows you to design all the methods you need for handeling the data mostly inside the class for both easier reading and maintaining. Tho this might take up more then if you wanted to go with a datatable, but considering its not more then 20 objects it would still be small enough for it not to be considered bad.

Comment: Why would having more than 20 object be considered bad?

Comment: well its not about wether 20 or 40 objects is bad, but having 40k objects in a application with limited amout of memory isnt ideal

Comment: Thanks this is very helpful. I awarded @rbaghbanli the answer because it fits my use-case better though; the header can be dynamic. Your answer is still correct of course because the List<Dictionary> from the other answer will be a public property of a separate class.